# ¿Bloquear botón actualizar del navegador?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo para bloquear el boton de retroceso del navegador.

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
        window.onpopstate = function () {
            history.go(1);
            alert('Si desea abandonar la asignación pulse \"Cancelar\"');  
        };
```

También lo tengo para que no se pueda recargar la pagina con `F5` y `Ctrl + r`, el problema viene cuando actualizo la pagina con el botón actualizar del navegador, que me actualiza la pagina pero me salta un error de que no la encuentra.

La pregunta seria si hay alguna manera de bloquear el botón actualizar del navegador

Answer (score 3):

No, no puedes.
Lo que puedes hacer, es mostrar una alerta cuando el usuario intente cerrar la pestaña o cambiar de url, o bien refrescar:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
```

Te paso un ejemplo funcionando:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aMOWKw